# Automated script to change user photos in Microsoft Exchange 2013 (powershell)

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a simple script, that gets all users from Exchange, scans for their photos in folder (name.jpg), then updates the photo.

The porblem is - when it tries to change the photo for ANYONE except me - it generated a very big ERROR "Error from proxxy server Set-UserPhoto -Identity $someone -PictureData: LOTS OF NUMBERS -Change;$False" Error - Request entry too large.
Here is part of the code with this script.

```
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
[Array]$AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All | Select-Object DisplayName
$i = 0
$p = 0
$e = 0
Add-Content $logPATH ("`Read Successful`n")
Add-Content $logPATH ("`rPhoto folder path: `n" + $PATH + "\PHOTOS\")
$photoPATH = $PATH + "\PHOTOS\"
foreach ($CurUser in $AllUsers) 
{
    $i++;
        $search = $CurUser.DisplayName + ".jpg"
        $curname = $CurUser.DisplayName
        $pathp = $photoPATH  + $search
        if (Test-Path ($pathp))
        {
            #'photo will be added'
            $p++
            $photo = ([Byte[]] $(Get-Content -Path $pathp -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0))
            $curname
            Try
            {
                Set-UserPhoto  $curname -PictureData $photo #-Confirm:$False
            }
            Catch
            {
                Add-Content $ERRORPATH ($_  + "`n")
            }
            Add-Content $logPATH ("`rDone: Photo updated for user " + $CurUser.DisplayName + "`n")
        }
        else
        {
            $e++
            Add-Content $logPATH ("`rERROR: Cant find photo for user: " + $CurUser.DisplayName + "`n")
        }
}
```

Sorry for broken english.

EDIT: Here is the fill error text:
Error proxxy server "Set-UserPhoto -PictureData: [Lots of NUMBERS, probably pic. data] -Identity: [name],  -Confirm:$False" for server [our server].outlook.com: ServerVersion 15.00.0995, method PSWS

The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-UserPhoto], CmdletProxyException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.CmdletProxyException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Reci
   pientTasks.SetUserPhoto

My thoughts - entry is too large because it contais full code for photo. But somehow it works for ME.

Comment: You should post the full error. As well as that, it blatantly looks like a permissions issue since one user(you) can execute the code successfully. This question would fit better on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I cant post the full error, because my Windows version in not in english. I will Edit the main question with everything i can find though.

Comment: Also, im pretty sure its not about permissions.

Comment: If this is O365 exchange then your local settings will have near to nothing impact. Therefore I maintain this is an issue with permissions/roles since one user can execute the code and another can't. Have you tried authenticating as a different user on your machine? You can also try this, it appears to have worked for some: `Set-UserPhoto $curname  -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($pathp))`

Comment: Yes. I know that its not about permission - i have all admin rights in O365. And yes, i tried this line too, same error. And if i log in as different user - i can change different photo (for that user only).

Comment: From what i remember about Exchange permissions, simply being an admin does give full permission to all objects. This has all hallmarks of a permissions issue.

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132(v=exchg.150).aspx, you will need "Organization Management", "Recipient Management" and "Help Desk" permissions on the objects you want to manage.

Comment: Still nothing. Currently i have Organization Management permissions, and still get this error.

Comment: http://community.office365.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-userfiles/00-00-37-47-37-Attached+Files/5850.error.jpg here is a screenshot of the same error. From microsoft community questions, unanswered for half a year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the url in the Session Line.
?proxymethod=rps
So it looks like this.

> $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange
>   -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/**?proxymethod=rps**
>   -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
>       Import-PSSession $Session

I got this from Microsoft support Patrick Reynolds (Allyis Inc)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug.  I opened a case with MS recently.  They are working on it.  You can upload up to a 10K photo for your own account, but are limited to around 1K for other users, regardless of your rights.  I am a global admin for example.  YOu are stuck with AD sync for this process at the moment